# Is CS.SE broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, questions

As of now (2022/11/01 12:00 UTC), there hasn't be new activity on CS.SE in the last 9 hours; last question appearing was posted 17 hours ago. I myself have asked a question 11 hours ago that appears on my profile, but not on the front page.

There seem to be [some broken things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383417/a-number-of-things-seem-to-have-broken-simultaneously) on SE, but I am not sure this is related (some SE, like [tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) still have new questions appearing).

I am not even sure this post will work on cs.meta… Does anyone have any information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LGTM:

[image]

Has the problem has been fixed for you as well? There may have been a localized hickup in a CDN, too, in which case you may be having issues impossible to reproduce elsewhere.

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed, yes, I will delete this post soon.

Comment: @Nathaniel Cool! No need to delete, I'll just mark it as "done".